# How can I get the max value on scores from Core Data?

Tags: core-data

Is it possible to return all values for a certain person and get their max score

```
let barScore: String = "9.246"

let numbers = [1, 6, 3, 9.245, 4, 6]

//numbers.minElement()
let value = numbers.maxElement()

if (Float(value!) < Float(barScore)) {

    print("True")

} else {

    print("False")
}
```

That works fine, but can't seem to get equivalent from core data.

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MeetResult")

        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "gymnast.fullName = %@", "\(gymnastNameText.text!)")

        do {

            let results = try AD.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [MeetResult]

            let value = results.maxElement()
            for result in results {

                print("Gymnast Name: \(gymnastNameText.text!)")
                print("Bar Score: \(result.barsScore!)")
            }

        } catch {

            fatalError("Falied to get results")

        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at ordering the results and limiting the results to only return 1?

Comment: @dudeman thanks, I will try that.